# Pasar datos de un dataGridViewa otro dataGridView (Padre a Hijo)

Tags: c#

Tengo un **dataGridView** con datos, cargados desde **SQL Server**, esto esta en un formulario principal,
cree un formulario aparte y este tiene un **dataGridView**  y a este dataGridView le quiero cargar con los datos del otro formulario es decir pasar los datos de padre a hijo presionando un botón
este el código que cree para pasar los datos

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //CAPTURAMOS VALOR DE LA FILA SELECCIONADA DG FORM1
            string A = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string B = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            string C = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            string D = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            string E = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            string F = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            string G = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            string H= this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            string I = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();

            //PASAMOS  DE FORM1  A FORM2
            Productos dato = new Productos();
            foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                if (frm.Name == "Productos")
                {
                    dato = (Productos)frm;
                    dato.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(A, B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I);

                    this.Close();
                    break;
                }
                dato.Show();
            }

        }
```

pero cuando pasa la segunda vez por el foreach me sale la siguiente excepción

**System.InvalidOperationException: 'Colección modificada; puede que no se ejecute la operación de enumeración.'**

¿Como puedo solucionar esto o hay otra forma mas de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes usar DataSource del dataGridView1.

Por ejemplo tengo la clase Producto

```
public class Producto {
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public double Precio { get; set; }
}
```

Y luego llenamos una lista con los productos

```
 productos = new List<Producto>() {
                new Producto(){ Nombre = "Papas", Precio = 213},
                new Producto(){ Nombre = "Coca", Precio = 345}
            };
```

Y con esto agregamos los productos a la tabla Padre

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = productos;
```

Y para cambiar los datos de la tabla padre a la hija solo haces esto (esto lo pondrías en el boton)

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
 dataGridView2.DataSource = productos;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo quieres pasar a otro form en el costructor del Form haces esto

```
 public Form2(List<Producto> productos) {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = productos;
 }
```

Y para abrir el form

```
   new Form2(productos).Show();
```

Comment: Pero esto esta en el mismo formulario necesito es pasar de un formulario a otro

Comment: Hola con formulario te refieres a ventana? si es eso solo pasa la variable productos a la otra ventana y asignasela al otro datagrid